# How to install numpy with mingw in windows, 64bit, python-2.7?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, numpy, 64-bit, mingw

I am trying to install numpy in cmd, 
before this, I have already installed easy_install, pip and mingw, also I have gave the PATH of mingw.By the way, I failed to settle it by vcvarsall.bat.
I use this:

```
python setup.py install build -compiler=mingw32
```

but it return to this:

```
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  commands have different --compiler options: ['ompiler=mingw32', 'mingw32'], using first in list as default
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'nt' with 'ompiler=mingw32' compiler
```

I am stuck to it and becoming deeply troubled. How should I do to finish it? (very appreciate if someone could help me.)

Comment: is `'ompiler=mingw32'` the right syntax, or are you missing a leading `c` in there?

Comment: thanks, should I add a leading c first? or you could tell me how to do it.